# JCRExportCommand execute() throws exception error in magnolia cms

Tags: magnolia

I would like to create a YAML export file on my local folder for the node on which I executed the Custom Action. The code below gives me NullPointerException:

`java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:364)
info.magnolia.repository.WorkspaceMapping.getWorkspaceMapping(WorkspaceMapping.java:124) 
info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager.getSession(DefaultRepositoryManager.java:308) 
info.magnolia.context.DefaultRepositoryStrategy.internalGetSession(DefaultRepositoryStrategy.java:61) 
info.magnolia.context.AbstractRepositoryStrategy.getSession(AbstractRepositoryStrategy.java:75)  info.magnolia.context.AbstractContext.getJCRSession(AbstractContext.java:124) info.magnolia.importexport.command.JcrExportCommand.execute(JcrExportCommand.java:117) 
ch.xxx.module.versioning.MyAction.execute(MyAction.java:60)`

```
public class MyAction extends AbstractMultiItemAction<xxxVersioning>  {


public MyAction(xxxVersioning definition, JcrItemAdapter item, UiContext uiContext) {
    super(definition, item, uiContext);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



@Override
public void execute() {

    //export nodes from a JCR workspace
    JcrExportCommand exporter = new JcrExportCommand();
    //sets export format to yaml
    exporter.setFormat("yaml");


    //setup the root directory for exports
    File rootDir = new File("/Users/asusti/Downloads/yamlExport");
    // clean up first
    rootDir.delete();
    rootDir.mkdirs();

    //get root node
    Node node = (Node) getItems().get(0).getJcrItem();
    try {
        exporter.setPath(node.getPath());
        File file = new File(rootDir+node.getName()+".yaml");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        exporter.setOutputStream(out);
        exporter.execute(MgnlContext.getInstance());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Do I have to set some other methods for the exporter before I execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the name of the workspace you want to export via `JcrExportCommand#setRepository()`. E.g.

```
exporter.setRepository("website");
```

to export the web site workspace.